# How do I add jQuery UI to my bundle in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The Visual Studio template has

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

in `BundleConfig.cs` and I want to add `jquery-ui.min.js` to the bundle. So I did

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"));
```

but now my I'm getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

in my JS console. What should I have done if I wanted to add `jquery-ui.min.js` to the bundle, or do I need to add it separately?

Comment: Look at your rendered HTML. Is the order of the scripts correct? `jquery.js` will need to be listed before `jquery-ui.js`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to only create 1 `ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")`. You are creating 2 with the same name (`"~/bundles/jquery"`) and the second one, which doesn't have the jQuery framework included, is overwriting the first

Like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"));
```

Also of course make sure those paths are correct and that both jquery and jquery ui exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to only create just one `ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")`.

same this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"));
```

Make sure those paths are correct and that both jquery and jquery ui exist.

Answer (score -2):

Can you reference using NuGet manager

[image]